# ngx-intl-tel-input angular library throwing error

Tags: html, angular

I followed the library instructions of installation and added component to my app template,
getting this error:
"ERROR in Symbol NgxIntlTelInputComponent declared in /node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/lib/ngx-intl-tel-input.component.d.ts is not exported from ngx-intl-tel-input/lib/ngx-intl-tel-input.module"

someone knows what is the cause?

Comment: Did you import `NgxIntlTelInputModule` into your app.module.ts file?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I figured that the npm install from the docs of this library was pointing to an older version, changing the version manually in the package.json to the newer version solved the bug:

```
"@angular-material-extensions/select-country": "^2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not importing the library correctly, do this:

```
import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input'
```